# Space travel - communication of the arrival time

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, interstellar-travel

I have a particular passion for space travel and so, for fun, I'm trying to identify the possible problems in comunication systems for a spaceship that moves at sensible fraction of speed of light in reference to the Earth.

Our astronauts are coming to the Earth and they want to send to Earth Control the time of their arrival.

If ship sends to the Earth two signals containing the send time on the ship reference system, on the Earth is possible to know the $\Delta T_{onship}$.

Is the $\Delta T_{onship}$ the only information that I need to know the time of their arrival on the Earth in the Earth reference frame?

I think no, because Lorentz transformations are simply rotations of the motion system with respect to the Earth system, and therefore say nothing about the displacement of the origin of the two systems, in fact

$\begin{eqnarray}
\left(\begin{array}{c}c\Delta t_{onship}\\\Delta\vec{x}_{onship}\end{array}\right) = \gamma \left(\begin{array}{c c}1 & -\beta \\ -\beta & 1\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{c}c\Delta t_{eatrh}\\\Delta \vec{x}_{earth}\end{array}\right) 
\end{eqnarray}$

so i can obtain

$\begin{eqnarray}\left\lbrace\begin{array}{c} c\Delta T_{onship}= \gamma(c\Delta T_{onearth} -\beta\Delta \vec{x}_{onearth})\\\Delta\vec{x}_{onship} = \gamma(\Delta\vec{x}_{on earth} - \beta c\Delta t_{onearth})\end{array}\right.\end{eqnarray}$

In this way I can evaluate only the speed of the ship, and I have $\Delta \vec{x}_{on earth}$ and $\Delta \vec{x}_{on ship}$ that I don't know how to use.

What more informations the ship must send to Earth control to evaluate the arrival time?

Comment: For the Earth to workout the distance at least one signal must travel both ways. For example the Earth send a signal and the ship reflect it back. Time dilation doesn't depend on distance between Earth and the ship. Hence, it is not possible to evaluate the distance with signal alone from the ship.